# Run some code before and after a method in Java without AOP frameworks?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, spring-aop, java-11

I wan't to run a code block before and after a method call in Java.

this is what I want in Java.
in the below example `makeSomeHttpCallAndGetData`, `readSomeOtherDataFromAFile` can be any arbitrary code block and can have different return types.

```js
   beforeAfterWrapper = fn => {
      logSomething();
      openDbConnection();
     
      fn();

      closeDbConnection();
      logSomething();
   }

   @beforeAfterWrapper
   function actualFunction() {
       return makeSomeHttpCallAndGetData();
   }

   @beforeAfterWrapper
   function anotherActualFunction() {
       return readSomeOtherDataFromAFile();
   }
```

Can we do it in java, using any functional constructs or reflection? I don't want to use any AOP frameworks. But it would be great if there are any leads to implement my own AOP sort of library just for this one use case.

I know AOP frameworks are build for this purpose, But I wanted to learn how to implement those by ourselves. In dynamically typed languages it's easy to implement these things. Curious to understand how it works in statically typed language as Java.

Comment: AOP frameworks were invented for doing exactly this.

Comment: You could build a `Proxy` around your class which adds the desired functionality, and then use the proxy rather than the constructed class whenever you need to...  But as @Henry says, an AOP library would probably do it better.

Comment: [Here's](https://ideone.com/8uBmmU) a quick example.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I know AOP frameworks are build for this purpose, But I wanted to learn how to implement those by ourselves. In dynamically typed languages it's easy to implement these things. Curious to understand how it works in statically typed language as Java.

Comment: There's a talk which covered very much this https://www.infoq.com/presentations/8-lines-code-refactoring/

Comment: You could also write an agent. Beware - that's not trivial.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html